# Difficulty determining the number of elements of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ divisible by $x^2 + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am having difficulty determining how many elements of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ can be divided by $x^2 + 1$. I know that $x^5 + x^3 + 1$ cannot be reduced further, but I'm not sure how that can be used (or if it can be used) to solve this problem. Considering that there are infinite possibilities for a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, with $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1) = \{w + (x^5 + x^3 + 1)  | w \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]\}$, I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are infinite possibilities for a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, but the number of elements of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1) $ is very much finite.

Comment: @Arthur Is my definition for the quotient ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1) = \{w + (x^5 + x^3 + 1)  | w \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]\}$ correct? If my definition is correct, I'm confused as to how the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ could be finite.

Comment: Yes, that's the right definition. Now note that while you have infinitely many choices for $w$, that doesn't result in infinitely many cosets. For instance, $0+(x^5+x^3+1)=x^5+x^3+1+(x^5+x^3+1)$. And this kind of collapse happens all over the place, resulting in a total of $32$ distinct cosets in the quotient ring.

Comment: @Arthur Understood :D, I can see this collapse happening. Just to make sure my understanding of finite fields is correct, isn't $x^5 + x^3 + 1 + (x^5 + x^3 + 1) = 2x^5 + 2x^3 + 2 = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$, since $2 = 0 \in \mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: The parenthesis around $(x^5+x^3+1)$ means ideal, not just parentheses.

Comment: @Arthur Understood, that makes sense now :D. You state that in the quotient ring in total, there are 32 distinct cosets, but do you mind explaining how you figured out that there were 32 distinct cosets? Is there a systematic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $x^5+x^3+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, as you pointed out. Therefore, $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ is ring-isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$, which you can write as $\mathbb{F}_{32}$.

Your question could mean one of two things:

- Let $f:\mathbb{F}_2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{32}$ be a homomorphism of rings such that $\text{Ker}(f)$ is the ideal generated by $x^5+x^3+1$. Let $t$ be the image of $x$ under this $f$. How many elements of $\mathbb{F}_{32}$ are divisible by $t^2+1$? The answer is "all of them", because $t^2+1\neq0$ and $\mathbb{F}_{32}$ is a field.
- Which polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{32}[y]$ are divisible by $y^2+1$? Well, that's nothing more than the ideal generated by $y^2+1$, which would be the case in the polynomial ring over any field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (upvoted). Would you mind explaining why $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ is ring-isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ is a field because the ideal generated by $x^5+x^3+1$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: @ChrisSanders Be careful equating polynomials with polynomial functions. The polynomial $x^2-x\in\Bbb F_2[x]$ evaluates to $0$ everywhere, but it isn't the zero polynomial.

Comment: Anyway @FernandoTorres this link will be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577095/if-fx-in-bbb-z-p-x-is-irreducible-with-p-prime-and-deg-fx-n-then?rq=1

Comment: @ChrisSanders Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it :D. Sorry again if this is a beginner question, but would you mind explaining why my question could mean one of two things as stated in your answer?

Comment: just the ambiguity of "polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$"

Comment: @ChrisSanders The problem actually stated "elements in" instead of "polynomials in" (I just made that correction). In that case, my question meets your first bullet point, correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @ChrisSanders I understand that the quotient ring $\mathbb{F_2}[x]/(x^5 + x^3 + 1)$ has 32 elements since there are $32$ possible remainders when any polynomial in $\mathbb{F_2}[x]$ is divided by $x^5 + x^3 + 1$ since there are $2^5$ polynomials with a degree less than $5$. However, I'm confused why introducing the homomorphism/kernel concepts is necessary: I thought that the # of elements in the quotient ring divisible by $x^2 + 1$ are just the multiples of $x^2 + 1$ by a polynomial in $F_2[x]$ which are in the $32$ possible polynomial remainders ($0, x^2 + 1, x(x^2 + 1), (x + 1)(x^2 + 1))$.